# NextJs - Add HTML Lang attribute to custom _document in object notation

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to set the `<html lang="...">` tag on a NextJs application with object notation.

Im rendering a serverStylesheet for Styled-components so my current `_document` file looks like this:

```
class CustomDocument extends Document {
static getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
    });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <>
          { initialProps.styles }
          { sheet.getStyleElement() }
        </>
      ),
    };
  } finally {
    sheet.seal();
  }
}}
```

I've seen a lot of articles about how to do it with rendering regular JSX components, but i want to do it with the object notation.

Answer (score 6):

You can return a custom `render()` from within that class which will allow you to decorate `<html>` with the `lang` attribute you want.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

This is your full code:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

More info here - [Link to docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-document)

> All of `<Html />`, `<Head />`, `<Main />` and `<NextScript />` are required for page to be properly rendered.

Comment: This is not a dynamic lang attribute. This is a hard coded 'en'